# Continuous Function on a Closed Bounded Set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then that function is bounded and uniformly continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Theorem : Let $A$ be closed bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. then $f$ is bounded and uniformly continuous on $A$.

I've been trying to prove this theorem, my idea is to prove it for  $n=1$ first, then generate for $n>1$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can someone give me another proof for this theorem? I'm not sure with my proof. Thanks.

Comment: Well, show us your proof and tell us please where you're stuck.

Comment: Homework should be marked as such.

Comment: See [Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) and [Heine-Cantor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine-Cantor_theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @DonAntonio pleas check it below.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for edited.

Comment: @geeneper thank you for your suggestion. I'll try to proof with your suggestion. :)
but, please for you comment for my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As genepeer points out, your assignment is essentially to prove the Heine-Cantor theorem for compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here is an idea for how to do that using some basic point-set topology.

- The Heine-Borel theorem is an essential tool for dealing with closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What does it say about $A$?
- What do you know about the image of a compact set under a continuous map? Now apply Heine-Borel again.
- To see that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, in the definition of continuity we need $\delta$ to not depend on the point $x\in A$. Pick $\varepsilon > 0$ and use continuity to find a $\delta$ for each $x\in A$. Cover $A$ by $B(x,\delta(x))$. Now use compactness. Can you find a $\delta$ that must work for every point in $A$?

Comment: @Neil thank for your comment, **1** from Heine-Borel Theorem, I have $A$ is compact. **2** How to check the image ? please give me a clue. :) **3** this is my problem. sorry I can give you vote up, but surely your answer is help me.

Comment: @machi **2** There's a basic fact from topology that the continuous image of a compact set is compact. **3** One definition of compactness is that every open cover of a compact space has a finite subcover.

Comment: thank very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1) $A$ is closed bounded in $\mathbb R$ iff $A$ is compact

2) $f(A)$ is compact. Why? Note that $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous

3) [Used Heine-Cantor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine-Cantor_theorem)

Comment: Just a thought: If machi is being asked to prove a version of Heine-Cantor, then he/she should not use it in the proof.

Comment: Maybe. Your proof is nice; very appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean that your hints are wrong, just that the student should read the proof of Heine-Cantor instead of citing it.

Comment: @Paul thank you very much, I can use this proof if I proof that $\mathbb{R}^n$ with it's norm is a metric space first, right?

Comment: YOU are right:)